Notepad++ How to bind column selection mode to the right mouse + hold down button?
I would like to enter vertical editing/selection mode by clicking the right mouse, holding it down, and dragging the mouse.
How would I do this in notepad++

Alt key + Left mouse button

You can't rebind that. You'd need a plugin/script for this

why? column mode is alt+select in most Windows apps including MS Word

It is a very awkward combination for me.  I'm used to slick edit which allows me to only use a mouse.
